# Keep ASP.NET Multiview in current ActiveViewIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

In my ASP.NET Web Forms, I have a MultiView that, when it is on ActiveViewIndex 2, will always go back to ActiveViewIndex 0 when a postback is done. When I insert/update a row in the database, I need it to show on the current ActiveViewIndex after it submits to the database. How do I keep it on the current ActiveViewIndex after the web form submits? Maybe this can be done using ViewState but I have never used it before so I wouldn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

For storing per-page data you can use ViewState, or have hidden input field which will preserve data after each post-back.
Viewstate is like a dictionary: when view 2 is displayed store that to viewstate (`ViewState["activeTab"] = 2;`), and on page load check if there's some value in viewstate, and change active view index if it is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["activeIndex"] != null)
        multiView.ActiveViewIndex = (int) ViewState["activeIndex"];
}
```

Comment: The ViewState remained at 0 the whole time, even after submitting the form. So it just went back to the 0 index.

Comment: That's strange, is view state disabled? You can try using hidden input field, content is preserved between postbacks!